# Permanent Redirect dynamic url in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

my website keeps generating dynamic search urls, there are thousands. I need to redirect them all to one url. They all start the same website.com/**CATEGORY**/random/random

How can I make URLs that contain the word **(/category/)** to 301 redirect website.com/category ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex, you're already using redirect match.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

'$' matches the end of the url. In your example:

redirectMatch 301 ^/user/(.+)$ http://example.com/category/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.

So what is this /user/ ? For me then would be redirectMatch 301 ^/category/(.+)$ http://example.com/category/ . Correct? This would then find /category/ directory and if found, 301 them all to example.com/category ?

Once again thanks for taking time to answer.